# mySQL starts with in 2 directions

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, sql-like

I have the following table

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|  ID   | Name1 | Name2 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|      1| Steve | Steven| - true
|      1| Steven| Steve | - true
|      1| Max   | Steve | - false
|      1| Steve | Steve | - true
+-------+-------+-------+
```

and i need to determine rows, where `Name1` starts with `Name2` or `Name2` starts with `Name1`

**question:**

is there a better way than `Name2 LIKE Concat(Name1, '%') OR Name1 LIKE Concat(Name2, '%')`

this example is a bit simplified, because `Name1` is a huge subselect and something like `Concat(Name1, '%') LIKE Concat(Name2, '%')` would increase the performance of my application a lot

**update:**

to point out my problem, the complete select looks like

`(SELECT Name FROM User JOIN UserGroup ON User.UserID = UserGroup.UserID JOIN Company  ON Company.UserID = User.UserID WHERE UserGroup.Range > 2 AND User.Create > '2010-01-01' AND Company.Country = 'CH' ORDER BY User.StartDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS Name2`

so the statement from above looks like

`(SELECT Name FROM User JOIN UserGroup ON User.UserID = UserGroup.UserID JOIN Company  ON Company.UserID = User.UserID WHERE UserGroup.Range > 2 AND User.Create > '2010-01-01' AND Company.Country = 'CH' ORDER BY User.StartDate DESC LIMIT 1) LIKE Concat(Name1, '%') OR Name1 LIKE Concat((SELECT Name FROM User JOIN UserGroup ON User.UserID = UserGroup.UserID JOIN Company  ON Company.UserID = User.UserID WHERE UserGroup.Range > 2 AND User.Create > '2010-01-01' AND Company.Country = 'CH' ORDER BY User.StartDate DESC LIMIT 1), '%')`

and the select is called twice - there must be a way to fetch `Name2` only once from the database

Comment: Your method is fine.  However, you should probably be doing complex calculations in the `from` clause.

Comment: You could try and use [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) instead, to check if one is a substring of the other, and if so if the position of the occurrence is 1 – that would at least eliminate the concact-with-percent-sign part. `LOCATE(Name1, Name2) = 1 OR LOCATE(Name2, Name1) = 1`

Comment: In your updated SQL, where is Name1 is coming from?

Comment: Name2 was just a placeholder for the nested select statement, Name1 is a field from the overlying select statement

Comment: Sorry, still not following. The edited SQL says:    (big-select) LIKE Concat(Name1,'%') OR Name1 LIKE Concat(big-select, %).   Is Name1 yet another select statement? Is this all part of a WHERE clause?

Comment: _Is this all part of a WHERE clause?_ yes

Comment: I think I understand. I have updated my answer below to discuss how to avoid duplicating of the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe quicker:

```
select *
from table1
WHERE substring(name2,1,length(name1))=name1
```

Comment: isn't that only one way? `SELECT SUBSTRING('Steve',1,LENGTH('Steven'))='Steven'` returns `0`

Comment: You are right:
SELECT *
from table1
WHERE (substring(name2,1,length(name1))=name1 or substring(name1,1,length(name2))=name2)

Comment: ok but that's a change for the worse - "name" is called 3 times

Comment: Maybe you could use "having" clause?

Comment: Select  (select .......) as name1, (select .........) as name2
from table
having (name1 REGEXP name2 or name2 REGEXP name1)

Answer (score 1):

As commented by others, your method is fine. However there is a way write it with an equality rather `OR` and two `LIKE` clauses. The idea is to take the minimum length of the two names, truncate both names to that length, and then compare them.

```
select *, 
LEFT(Name1, LEAST(LENGTH(Name1), LENGTH(Name2))) =
LEFT(Name2, LEAST(LENGTH(Name1), LENGTH(Name2))) 
from Table1
```

This is probably more efficient, just by avoiding OR and LIKE. It's messier to read though, and you said that it would need to be combined with another complex expression... To clean it up you could put the comparison logic into a stored function.

** Update ** I see in your updated example that Name2 is actually a nested SELECT, and that you'd rather not run it 2 or 3 times.

You can use nested queries. The inner query builds a table of rows that looks just like the simplified example of your original question. Something like:

```
SELECT ID, Name1,
(SELECT Name FROM User JOIN UserGroup ON User.UserID = UserGroup.UserID JOIN Company  ON Company.UserID = User.UserID WHERE UserGroup.Range > 2 AND User.Create > '2010-01-01' AND Company.Country = 'CH' ORDER BY User.StartDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS Name2
FROM Table1
```

Now name this "table" PotentialMatch, and wrap it with an outer query that picks the rows that match. Something like:

```
SELECT PotentialMatch.ID, PotentialMatch.Name1 FROM 
(SELECT ID, Name1,
  (SELECT Name FROM User JOIN UserGroup ON User.UserID = UserGroup.UserID JOIN Company  ON Company.UserID = User.UserID WHERE UserGroup.Range > 2 AND User.Create > '2010-01-01' AND Company.Country = 'CH' ORDER BY User.StartDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS Name2
FROM Table1) PotentialMatch
WHERE LEFT(PotentialMatch.Name1, LEAST(LENGTH(PotentialMatch.Name1), LENGTH(PotentialMatch.Name2))) =
LEFT(PotentialMatch.Name2, LEAST(LENGTH(PotentialMatch.Name1), LENGTH(PotentialMatch.Name2)))
```

Or if you prefer, you could use this subquery technique just as well with your original `LIKE` comparisons:

```
SELECT PotentialMatch.ID, PotentialMatch.Name1 FROM 
(SELECT ID, Name1,
  (SELECT Name FROM User JOIN UserGroup ON User.UserID = UserGroup.UserID JOIN Company  ON Company.UserID = User.UserID WHERE UserGroup.Range > 2 AND User.Create > '2010-01-01' AND Company.Country = 'CH' ORDER BY User.StartDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS Name2
FROM Table1) PotentialMatch
WHERE PotentialMatch.Name1 LIKE CONCAT(PotentialMatch.Name2, '%') 
OR PotentialMatch.Name2 LIKE CONCAT(PotentialMatch.Name1, '%')
```

Without a SQLFiddle I can't test these, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: in your example i have to select `Name1` 3 times instead of 2 times

Comment: True, but referencing columns from a row repeatedly is not expensive. Have OR in a WHERE clause can be expensive because it makes it harder for the database to use indices efficiently; an OR sometimes forces it to run through the rows more than one.  And LIKE is a powerful general-purpose string-parsing function that is not going to be as efficient as truncating the string and performing a one-way comparison...

Comment: My comments are theoretical; the difference may be negligible when applied to your problem. I will add a note to that effect.

Comment: I understand from your update why you want to eliminate multiple references to one of the columns. I've tried to address this in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table1 
WHERE   Name2 REGEXP Name1;
```

Or do this for both directions:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table1 
WHERE (
CASE WHEN (SELECT Name2  REGEXP Name1) = 0 THEN 
0 ELSE 
(SELECT Name1 REGEXP Name2)
END) = 0;
```

Comment: `SELECT 'Steve' REGEXP 'Steven'` returns `0`

Comment: but the result of `SELECT 'Steven' REGEXP 'Steve'` is `1`